# How can I make this SQL query the most effective?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I am making a website with a large pool of images added by users.

I want to choose randomly one image out of this pool, and display it to the user, but I want to make sure that this user has never seen this image before.

So i was thinking that: when a user views an image, I make a row INSERT in MYSQL that would say "This USER has watched THIS IMAGE at (TIME)" for every entry.
But the thing is, since there might be a lot of users and a lot of images, this table can easily grow to tens of thousands of entries quite rapidly.

So alternatively, it might be done like that:
I was thinking of making a row INSERT for every USER, and in ONE field, I insert an array all id's of images that user has watched.

I can even do that to the array:
base64_encode(gzcompress(serialize($array)

And then:
unserialize(gzuncompress(base64_decode($array))

What do you think I should do?
Is the encoding/decoding functions fast enough, or at least faster than the conventional way i was describing at the beginning of the post?

Is that compression good enough to store large chunks of data into only ONE database field? (imagine if the user has viewed thousands images?)

Thanks a lot

Comment: How will you know that the user has actually "seen" the image? Random might be good enough. :) How are you selecting the random image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in ONE field, I insert an array all id's

In almost all cases, serializing values like this is bad practice. Let the database do what it's designed to do -- efficiently handle large amounts of data. As long as you ensure that your cross table has an index on the user field, retrieving the list of images that a user has seen will not be an expensive operation, regardless of the number of rows in the table. Tens of thousands of entries is nothing.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your response. I will then go for the image_id/user_id method.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new table `UserImageViews` with columns `user_id` and `image_id` (additionally, you could add more information on the view, such as Date/Time, IP and Browser).

That will make queries like "What images the user has (not) seen" much faster.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Do you think that this method could be quite intense for the database, if the table has 10k+ rows?
Thanks
EDIT: I got the answer below. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Not necessarily, if you have the indexes in place. This is what a RDBMS is designed for. It will be worse if you use the "multiple data in one field" approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a table. Serializing data into a single field in a database is a bad practice, as the DBMS has no clue what that data represents and cannot be used in ANY queries. For example, if you wanted to see which users had viewed an image, you wouldn't be able to in SQL alone.

Tens of thousands of entries isn't much, BTW. The main application we develop has multiple tables with hundreds of thousands of records, and we're not that big. Some web applications have tables with millions of rows. Don't worry about having "too much data" unless it starts becoming a problem - the solutions for that problem will be complex and might even slow down your queries until you get to that amount of data.

EDIT: Oh yeah, and joins against those 100k+ tables happen in under a second. Just some perspective for ya...

Comment: Hi Ryan,
Thanks for your suggestions. Since I am on localhost, only have a few hundreds rows in it, and my queries take less than 0.01. 
1 second seems to me like an eternity for a computer :) but I will take your advice seriously. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think that tens of thousands of rows will be a problem for a database lookup. I will recommend using the first approach over the second.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to choose randomly one image out of this pool, and display it
>   to the user, but I want to make sure that this user has never seen
>   this image before.

For what it's worth, that's not a random algorithm; that's a shuffle algorithm. (Knowing that will make it easier to Google when you need more details about it.)  But that's not your biggest problem.

> So i was thinking that: when a user views an image, I make a row
>   INSERT in MYSQL that would say "This USER has watched THIS IMAGE at
>   (TIME)" for every entry.

Good thought. Using a table that stores the fact that a user has seen a specific image makes sense in your case. Unless I've missed something, you don't need to store the time. (And you probably shouldn't.  It doesn't seem to serve any useful business purpose.)  Something along these lines should work well.

```
-- Predicate: User identified by [user_id] has seen image identified by
-- [image_filename] at least once.
create table images_seen (
  user_id integer not null references users (user_id),
  image_filename not null references images (image_filename),
  primary key (user_id, image_filename)
);
```

Test that and look at the output of [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html). If you need a secondary index on image_filename . . .

```
create index images_seen_img_filename on images_seen (image_filename);
```

This still isn't your biggest problem.

The biggest problem is that you didn't test this yourself. If you know any scripting language, you should be able to generate 10,000 rows for testing in a matter of a couple of minutes.  If you'd done that, you'd find that a table like that will perform well even with several million rows.

I sometimes generate millions of rows to test my ideas before I answer a question on StackOverlow.

Learning to generate large amounts of random(ish) data for testing is a fundamental skill for database and application developers.

Comment: Hi Catcall, thanks for your great post and for letting me know in passing of the existence of EXPLAIN.

I was thinking of choosing user_id ONLY as the primary key, but why was your suggestion: "primary key (user_id, image_filename)"? Thanks a lot

Comment: @eric01: If "user_id" is the only column in the primary key, you'll be able to store only one image filename per user.

Comment: Oh ok, my first thought was that, in order to store more than one image filename per user, I would have to use another column called "id" as Primary (with auto-increment) and then user_id in the second column, and filename in the third column. But I guess it wouldn't be as fast..?

Comment: @eric01: If you have an id number as the primary key, and with no other constraints, you can repeat the user id and filename a million times.  So you can store a million copies of the same row. You don't want to do that. I'd suggest you play around with the code I wrote for you until you understand what it does and how it works.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am looking at that code and trying to understand. Regards